# Copy a file in a destination folder

Tags: linux, bash, file-copy

I have a file in a very long path, for example:

```
/opt/very/long/path/file1
```

I want to copy the file in this directory:

```
cp /opt/very/long/path/file1 /opt/very/long/path/file2
```

I don't want repeat this long path. I can go to the destination folder and copy:

```
cd /opt/very/long/path/
cp file1 file2
```

But I don't want change directory. One of the reason is: if I had many long paths I would have to go to directories every time.

```
cd /opt/very/long/path/
cp file1 file2
cd /opt/other/very/very/long/path/
cp fileA fileB
```

Another reasons are: I want to keep context and clear history (every command says what and where was copied).

Therefore, better is not change directory:

```
cp /opt/very/long/path/file1 /opt/very/long/path/file2
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileB
```

But I have to repeat paths.

There is a shortcut like this?

```
cp /opt/very/long/path/file1 ./file2
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA ./fileB
```

But a dot `.` means "current directory". **There is any character that means "destination directory" or "source directory"?**

```
cp /opt/very/long/path/file1 <destination>/file2
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA <destination>/fileB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brace expansion is nice for this:

```
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/{fileA,fileB}
```

... will expand to:

```
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileB
```

when it actually executes.

The command will show up in your history as you typed it, which preserves the paths:

```
$ history
  # ...
  508  cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/{fileA,fileB}
  509  history
```

Comment: I noticed only one disadvantage: **filenames autocomplete** isn't working. When I type `{` I have to type whole filename. When my filename is very long I can type `path/` and press `[TAB]` so it will autocomplete to `path/fileA`. Next I press `arrow left` **many times** to insert `{`, so I have: `path/{fileA`. Next I press `[END]` type `,` and **write manually** `fileB` (or select with mouse and copy-paste if filename is really very long), and at the end type `}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable with the very log path and use that variable instead in cp command.

e.g

```
export dir="/opt/very/long/path" 

cp "$dir"/file "$dir"/file2
```

Comment: note that there's no real need to export `dir` here

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync if you want to sync between 2 folders.

rsync can be used to sync in local host and remote hosts, too.

For the above scenario, it's used in localhost:

```
rsync -avzh sourcefolder destinationfolder
```

Comment: In this scenario, that still requires them to type /opt/other/very/very/long/path twice...

Answer (score 0):

You can type:

```
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA !#:1:h/fileB
```

it will expand in history to:

```
cp /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileA /opt/other/very/very/long/path/fileB
```

Explanation:

- `!#` - get current line
- `:1` - get first argument
- `:h` - get folder

(thanks for [this article](https://zwischenzugs.com/2019/08/25/seven-god-like-bash-history-shortcuts-you-will-actually-use/))

Disadvantage is that:

- you can't press `up arrow` to get command you typed, because it saved expanded in history,
- second filename autocomplete isn't working.